# XSD how to have maxOccurs to value of previous element count

Tags: xsd

Hi i need to create an xsd for a xml where there are many elements of name columns, and rows.

Kindly suggest the XSD, i have made cols as unbounded how should i make the element rows.

```
<cols>
    <id>a</id>
    <type>string</type>
</cols>
<cols>
    <id>b</id>
    <type>string</type>
</cols>
<cols>
    <id>c</id>
    <type>number</type>
</cols>
<rows>
    <c>
        <v>a</v>
    </c>
    <c>
        <v>b</v>
    </c>
    <c>
        <v>3</v>
    </c>
</rows>
<rows>
    <c>
        <v>c</v>
```

Comment: Please edit to rephrase your question, it is too vague about the format of your XML data. Be more specific. Post the XSD you got so far.

Answer (score 0):

The xml sample you posted as it is will not be valid against any schema. In-fact xml should never have multiple root nodes (as your example does). You need to wrap these in a single root node.

In answer to your question xsd does not support attribute values conditional on a count of the number of nodes in a node-set like you assume. The best you can do is use unbounded for your maxOccurs.

The schema you want will look similar to this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://mynamespace" targetNamespace="http://mynamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="cols">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="rows">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="c">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="v" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Hope this helps you